# Entity Framework 4 custom Data type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, types

I am starting to use Entity Framework 4. assuming I can not change the database fields.
I have a field DateAdded that is stored as YYYYMMDD and I would like to have the entity.DateAdded as a DateTime type. It would make it much easier to work with.

Is there a way to do a custom column data type mapping? or any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional property in a partial class for the entity that wraps the "raw" property.

```
namespace TheNamespace
{

  public partial class TheEntity
  {
      public DateTime DateAdded 
      {
         get {  }
         set {  }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to "hide" the raw property and only expose the additional one?

Comment: +1 I use this method for bit fields that are nullable in the database but need to be mapped to html checkboxes and can't be null in that instance. Works very well.

Comment: @everLearningStudent - I believe that you can set the property getter / setter scope in the properties of the entity model.  Try setting both of those to private.

Comment: Great, that completes the picture. And to preserve the variable name, I called the generated property DateAddedString ( in the model) and kept DateAdded for the property in the partial class. This way it is exposed as the same name as the database with the expected data type. Thank you all.